# Is it safe to mark step definitions with multiple attributes

Tags: methods, specflow

I have a series of steps which I want to be able to call from multiple points in my scenarios, so I have marked them with the all three attributes, like so:

```
[Given(@"I am logged in")]
[When(@"I am logged in")]
[Then(@"I am logged in")]
public void GivenIAmLoggedIn()
{
    ... some code ...
}
```

Now, I have not - so far - seen a failure while doing this, but is it safe? Am I making an assumption or should I create duplicates of those methods? (I'm thinking that something under the hood will conflict at a later time..?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing this for two years, hundreds of scenarios and steps and only encountered one issue which I cannot directly relate to having multiple attributes (Although it does). It's slightly strange having an action and an assert as the same code, as this example but I can see why you might use it. I have some that look like this:

```
[Given(@"I am a logged-in (.*) customer")]
[Given(@"I have successfully logged in")]
[Given(@"I am on the post login page")]
[When(@"I'm logged in")]
[Then(@"I can successfully log in")]

 public void GivenIAmLoggedIn(string customer = 'normal')
 {
    --SomeCode
 }
```

It might be more elegent to use the underscore method name - https://specflow.org/documentation/step-definition-styles/ if your regexis identical.